# What is the character length of datetimeoffset datatype in SQL Server / SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetimeoffset

Could you please explain how come (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss {+|-}hh:mm`) format is having 26 characters in datetimeoffset datatype in SQL Server? Is there is a space between `hh:mm:ss`  and `{+|-}hh:mm`?

Comment: Databases store date/time values using internal formats.  They are converted to strings for presentation purposes.  Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a space at position 28:

```
declare @o datetimeoffset;

select @o = getdate()

select 
    @o as [value], 
    len(convert(varchar(36), @o)) as [length],
    substring(convert(varchar(36), @o), 28, 1) as [27th character],
    ascii(substring(convert(varchar(36), @o), 28, 1)) as [27th character ascii]
```

Results:

```
value                               | length | 27th character | 27th character ascii
2017-10-24 09:18:36.0466667 +00:00  |  34    |                | 32
```